# Chrome extension sendResponse not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

There are numerous versions of this question, and I have reviewed them and tried many things to the best of my ability without success. I am new to chrome extensions, and I could be missing many things, but I don't know what.

First, I want to point out that I have copied several claimed working examples from various answers, and none of them work for me. I am using Chrome Version 58.0.3029.81 on Windows 7 Professional.

Whether it's my code, or examples I have copied, the code in the content script executes, and calls sendResponse with the correct response. Beyond that, nothing - the specified callback function is never executed.

Here is my current code:

manifest.json

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "TestExtension",
  "description": "...",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [ "content.js" ]
    }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Send a checkpoint request"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",    // allow any host
    "https://*/*"    // allow any secure host
  ]
}
```

popup.js

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function ()
{

    document.getElementById('extension_form').onsubmit = function ()
    {
        var elementName = "DataAccessURL";

        chrome.tabs.query(
        {
            active: true,
            currentWindow: true
        },
        function (tabs)
        {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
                tabs[0].id,
                { Method: "GetElement", data: elementName },
                function (response)
                {
                    debugger;
                    console.log("response:Element = " + response.Element);
                    alert(response.Element);
                });
        });



    };
});
```

content.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    console.log("In Listener");

    if (request.Method && request.Method == "GetElement")
    {
        var result = "";

        var element = request.data;

        console.log(element);

        var e = document.getElementById(element);

        if (e) result = e.innerHTML;

        console.log(result);

        sendResponse({ Element: result });

        return true;    // <-- the presence or absence of this line makes no difference
    }

});
```

Any clues would be appreciated. I simply do not understand why my callback is not being called.

Comment: The popup is a separate window which has its own console and devtools: rightclick the popup and choose Inspect to debug the code. Also make sure the content script is actually injected.

Comment: @wOxxOm: Thanks - the sendMessage in popup.js loads and executes fine. The listener code in content.js gets called and executes fine. It gets the correct data, and calls sendResponse with the result. But again, the callback specified as the third parameter to sendMessage never gets called. It has a debugger statement currently that never gets hit, even with the code showing in the separate devtools window as you suggest.

Comment: Sounds like the popup is getting closed before it can receive the response. When the popup is closed its environment (code/DOM) no longer exist.

Comment: @wOxxOm: The code executes as the result of a submit button click in a form in the popup. When I click the button, the popup never disappears - it seems to be open the entire time my code is executing, and remains open after execution is complete. It goes away when I click somewhere else in the browser. Is there a way it could still be 'closed' somehow?

Comment: `submit` event reloads the popup which means the old listeners and connections are destroyed so you need to preventDefault on the submit event.

Comment: @wOxxOm: That was it! Thank you very much. If you would submit this as an answer, I would be happy to accept. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User wOxxOm provided this answer in his comments.

In the popup.js example, I am attaching to the form 'onsubmit' event to trigger my code.

I had previously read that if the popup gets closed, it's code would no longer be there to be run. I could not visually tell in my case that, as wOxxOm pointed out, that the submit event reloads the popup. That was disconnecting my code.

In order to prevent the popup from reloading, I needed to prevent the default action on the submit event. I added an 'evt' parameter to accept the event argument to the submit, and called preventDefault as shown below.

```
document.getElementById('extension_form').onsubmit = function (evt)
{
    evt.preventDefault();
    ...
```

This allowed the sample to work as expected.

Thanks wOxxOm!